# Reordering rows in a data.frame?

Tags: r

All I need is to swap every two rows in this table... Basically swap every row containing 'chao1' with the next row, which certainly contains 'obs'.

All the examples I have come accross seem to have a previous reference for that, but what I am looking for, I think, is a bit different.

```
     Group.1                  var     S           se    
1    Cliona celata complex    chao1   800.5933    57.51779
2    Cliona celata complex    obs     495.4286    63.07360
3    Cliona viridis           chao1   432.5548    35.87778
4    Cliona viridis           obs     286.0000    55.32179
5    Dysidea fragilis         chao1   694.9129    74.85536
6    Dysidea fragilis         obs     357.6667    64.02170
7    Phorbas fictitius        chao1   851.6950    57.67145
8    Phorbas fictitius        obs     523.2500    23.57905
```

Thank you in advance for all the help!

Cheers,

André

Comment: Is `Cliona virids` in the third row is a typo?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, it is! -> viridis

Comment: So have you tried my solution? Should be very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data frame has an even number of rows you can do this:

```
n <- nrow(df)
x <- matrix(1:n, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
y <- x[,2:1]
inds <- as.numeric(t(y))
new.df <- df[inds,,drop=FALSE]
```

Comment: Although mine uses less lines, yours exploits the interplay between algebra and geometry.

Comment: @Bridgeburners , one more thing, the row numbers on my.df are not ordered. This is, the order of the table is the correct one, but the row.names column is as following (2,1,4,3...). Can you fix that? Thanks!

Comment: You could just say "rownames(new.df) <- NULL" or "rownames(new.df) <- seq(nrow(new.df))". Whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 4):

A quick way of doing this is using `data.table` devel version `setorder` which will reorder your data set in place too

```
#### To install development version
## library(devtools)
## install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)

library(data.table) # V >= 1.9.5
setorder(df, Group.1, -var)
#                 Group.1   var        S       se
# 2 Cliona celata complex   obs 495.4286 63.07360
# 1 Cliona celata complex chao1 800.5933 57.51779
# 4        Cliona viridis   obs 286.0000 55.32179
# 3        Cliona viridis chao1 432.5548 35.87778
# 6      Dysidea fragilis   obs 357.6667 64.02170
# 5      Dysidea fragilis chao1 694.9129 74.85536
# 8     Phorbas fictitius   obs 523.2500 23.57905
# 7     Phorbas fictitius chao1 851.6950 57.67145
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is something that works using a trick that David taught me just a few hours ago :). It also requires an even number of rows and them being ordered properly.

```
 df <- data.frame(g1=c("a","a","b","b"),var=c(1,2,3,4))
 df
 #   g1 var
 # 1  a   1
 # 2  a   2
 # 3  b   3
 # 4  b   4

 n <- nrow(df)
 sidx <- trunc(seq(0,n-1)/2)*2 + rep(c(1,0),n/2) + 1
 df <- df[sidx,]
 df

 #   g1 var
 # 2  a   2
 # 1  a   1
 # 4  b   4
 # 3  b   3
```